# How to create a countdown on a surfaceview canvas using a textview

Tags: android, eclipse, canvas, timer

I am trying to create a game and I am trying to put a countdown timer in it.
This is my WelcomePage Class which contains a button to start the game and also  the countdown timer.

```
public class WelcomePage extends Activity {

Spinner timerValueSpinner;


String[] timeValues;
Resources resourcePointer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature (Window. FEATURE_NO_TITLE );
    setContentView(R.layout.welcome_page);

    timerValueSpinner = (Spinner)this.findViewById(R.id.secondsSpinner);



    resourcePointer = getResources();
    timeValues = resourcePointer.getStringArray(R.array.seconds_list);



    launchButton();

}

public void launchButton(){
Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(WelcomePage.this,Main.class);


        if(timerValueSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition() > -1){
            int parsedSpinnerValue = 0;
            parsedSpinnerValue =    Integer.parseInt(timeValues[timerValueSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition()]);

            if(parsedSpinnerValue > 0){
                intent.putExtra("TimeValue", parsedSpinnerValue);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        }
    }

});


    }
```

This is the Main Class where I put the TextView which shows the Countdown Timer.

```
public class Main extends Activity {

Countdown timer;
 TextView statusTextVie;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature (Window. FEATURE_NO_TITLE );
    setContentView(new GameView(this));
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    int timeVal = extras.getInt("TimeValue", 0);

statusTextVie = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.timerVie);
 if (timeVal > 0){
        if(timer != null){
            timer.cancel();
        }
        timer = new Countdown((timeVal + 1) * Countdown.oneSecond, Countdown.oneSecond,statusTextVie);



        timer.start();
}
```

There is a problem with the setContentView(new GameView(this)); When I push the play button from the WelcomePage Class. The App stop and show "Unfortunately, (App Name) has stopped" When I change it to setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);,the app works but only the Countdown Timer and the game doesn't show.

This is my GameView Class which contains the surfaceview.

```
public class GameView extends SurfaceView {



private SurfaceHolder holder;
private GameLoopThread gameLoopThread;
private List<Sprite> sprites = new ArrayList<Sprite>();
private long lastClick;
private Bitmap bmpExplode;
private List<TempSprite> temps = new ArrayList<TempSprite>();

private SoundPool sounds;
private int booms;
private int msprite=30;
Countdown timer;

TextView statusTextVie = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.timerVie);
 String text = statusTextVie.getText().toString();


public GameView(Context context) {
    super(context);


    gameLoopThread = new GameLoopThread(this);
    holder = getHolder ();
    holder .addCallback(new Callback() {

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            boolean retry = true;
            gameLoopThread.setRunning(false);

            while (retry){
                try{
                    gameLoopThread.join();
                    retry= false;
                }catch (InterruptedException e){
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

            createSprites();
            gameLoopThread.setRunning(true);
            gameLoopThread.start();




        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {}
    }); 
    bmpExplode = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.deadline);
    sounds= new SoundPool(10,AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,0);
    booms=sounds.load(context,R.raw.boom,1);


}
 private void createSprites() {

     sprites.add(createSprite(R.mipmap.b1));
     sprites.add(createSprite(R.mipmap.b1));
     sprites.add(createSprite(R.mipmap.b1));
     sprites.add(createSprite(R.mipmap.b1));
     sprites.add(createSprite(R.mipmap.b1));
     sprites.add(createSprite(R.mipmap.b1));
     sprites.add(createSprite(R.mipmap.b1));
     sprites.add(createSprite(R.mipmap.b1));
     sprites.add(createSprite(R.mipmap.b1));
     sprites.add(createSprite(R.mipmap.b1));
     sprites.add(createSprite(R.mipmap.b1));
     sprites.add(createSprite(R.mipmap.b1));
     sprites.add(createSprite(R.mipmap.b1));
     sprites.add(createSprite(R.mipmap.b1));
     sprites.add(createSprite(R.mipmap.b1));
     sprites.add(createSprite(R.mipmap.b1));
     sprites.add(createSprite(R.mipmap.b1));
     sprites.add(createSprite(R.mipmap.b1));
     sprites.add(createSprite(R.mipmap.b1));
     sprites.add(createSprite(R.mipmap.b1));
        sprites.add(createSprite(R.mipmap.b2));
        sprites.add(createSprite(R.mipmap.b3));
        sprites.add(createSprite(R.mipmap.b4));
        sprites.add(createSprite(R.mipmap.b5));
        sprites.add(createSprite(R.mipmap.b6));
        sprites.add(createSprite(R.mipmap.b2));
        sprites.add(createSprite(R.mipmap.b3));
        sprites.add(createSprite(R.mipmap.b4));
        sprites.add(createSprite(R.mipmap.b5));
        sprites.add(createSprite(R.mipmap.b6));

 }
 private Sprite createSprite(int resouce) {
     Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resouce);
     return new Sprite(this,bmp);
```

}

```
@SuppressLint("WrongCall")
@Override
protected void onDraw (Canvas canvas) {

    canvas.drawColor (Color. BLACK );

    for (int i = temps.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        temps.get(i).onDraw(canvas);
  }
    for (Sprite sprite : sprites) {
        sprite.onDraw(canvas);
 }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastClick > 300) {
        lastClick = System.currentTimeMillis();
    synchronized (getHolder()) {
          float x=event.getX();
          float y=event.getY();
      for (int i = sprites.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
             Sprite sprite = sprites.get(i);
             if (sprite.isCollition(x,y)) {
                 if (i < msprite){
                     msprite--;
                     sounds.play(booms, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0,0, 1.5f);
                 }
                    sprites.remove(sprite);

                    temps.add(new TempSprite(temps, this, x, y, bmpExplode));
                    break;
             }
      }}
    }
      return true;
}
}
```

How do I put the TextView from the Main Class in the surfaceview canvas

Answer (score 0):

Use this library for countdown timer.
https://github.com/iwgang/CountdownView

> Gradle

```
compile 'com.github.iwgang:countdownview:2.1.2'
```

> Code

```
CountdownView mCvCountdownView = (CountdownView)findViewById(R.id.cv_countdownViewTest1);
mCvCountdownView.start(995550000); // Millisecond

// or
for (int time=0; time<1000; time++) {
    mCvCountdownView.updateShow(time);
}
```

> Layout

```
<cn.iwgang.countdownview.CountdownView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:isHideTimeBackground="true"
    app:isShowDay="true"
    app:isShowHour="true"
    app:isShowMinute="true"
    app:isShowSecond="true"
    app:isShowMillisecond="true"
    app:timeTextColor="#000000"
    app:timeTextSize="22sp"
    app:isTimeTextBold="true"
    app:suffixGravity="bottom"
    app:suffixTextColor="#000000"
    app:suffixTextSize="12sp"
    app:suffixHour="时"
    app:suffixMinute="分"
    app:suffixSecond="秒"
    app:suffixMillisecond="毫秒" />
```